# LeetCode - 3Sum Problem in Python - Time Limit Exceede

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a working solution for the [3Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) problem, but it doesn't pass all the test cases because it "exceeds the time limit." I passed 310 / 312 test cases on LeetCode, so I know it works. It's just the last 2 test cases that it takes too long for.

> Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets [nums[i],
> nums[j], nums[k]] such that i != j, i != k, and j != k, and nums[i] +
> nums[j] + nums[k] == 0.
>
> Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Here is my code:

```
def threeSum(nums):
    sol = []
    pos = 1
    nums.sort()

    def search(p, vals):
        l, r = 0, len(vals) - 1
        sols = []
        while l < p < r:
            if vals[l] + vals[p] + vals[r] == 0:
                sols.append([vals[l], vals[p], vals[r]])
                vals.pop(r)
                vals.pop(l)
                l, r = l, r - 2
                p -= 1
                continue
            if vals[l] + vals[p] + vals[r] > 0:
                r -= 1
            if vals[l] + vals[p] + vals[r] < 0:
                l += 1
        return sols

    while pos < len(nums) - 1:
        new_sol = search(pos, nums[:])
        for n in new_sol:
            if n not in sol:
                sol.append(n)
        pos += 1
    return sol
```

Can someone change my code to reduce the time complexity? Could you also describe what the time complexity of my current and the new code is? I want it to be my code, so I would appreciate it if it stayed similar to the one I provided and only had the necessary changes.

Comment: You should learn how to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script) your scripts so that you don't have to guess, or ask others for their input; profiling is an objective way to measure performance and determine what the slow parts are. If anything, you could at least find what parts are performing poorly before posting here, so that at least you make it clear to everyone that you're doing your due diligence and trying to provide as much information and effort as you can.

Comment: Such an error is typical when you don't use the exact algorithm that the problem writer expects you to use.

Comment: When this happens in Leetcode it usually means that the algorithm you've implemented isn't optimum. It may be functionally correct but just too slow

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Yes, that's pretty difficult without the code that LC actually runs, but that's an inherent problem with this type of question here. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Can you state the 3Sum problem at the beginning of your question? Readers should not have to figure that out for your code.

Comment: Instead of the pops in search, you can write `l += 1; r -= 1` and then you don't need to copy `nums` on every call. And use a set to store the triples rather than a list so the duplicate removal is efficient. Then your code is quadratic. As it's written it may be quadratic (but highly inefficient) or it may be cubic depending on how many unique solutions there can be to a threesum problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I submitted  for this problem quite some time ago.
IIRC it passed all tests.

```
from typing import List

def threeSum(nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    unique_triplets = []
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
        if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
            continue
        lo = i + 1
        hi = len(nums) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            target_sum = nums[i] + nums[lo] + nums[hi]
            if target_sum < 0:
                lo += 1
            if target_sum > 0:
                hi -= 1
            if target_sum == 0:
                unique_triplets.append([nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]])
                while lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[lo + 1]:
                    lo += 1
                while lo < hi and nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1]:
                    hi -= 1
                lo += 1
                hi -= 1
    return unique_triplets
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution which appears to pass all tests without timing out:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = set()
        ds = set()
        p = None
        nums.sort()
        for i, v in enumerate(nums[:-2], 1):
            if p != v:
                p = v
                ds.clear()
                for x in nums[i:]:
                    if x not in ds:
                        ds.add(-v-x)
                    else:
                        res.add((v, -v-x, x))
        return list(map(list, res))
```